# Does the C++ standard allow for an implementation to coalesce allocations?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was watching Jonathan Blow's video [*Ideas about a new programming language for games*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH9VCN6UkyQ&t=65m40s) in which he discusses a common pattern in games programming he calls 'joint allocation'. The idea is when you have a class with several members that are dynamically allocated arrays (could be `std::vector` but since they're fixed size, more like the proposed `std::dynarray`) you pre-allocate enough memory to store all of the array data and perform only one allocation big enough for all the arrays rather than one for each array.

He proposes direct language support for this pattern which got me to wondering whether the C++ standard allows for implementations to coalesce allocations in this way? It strikes me that this would require some heroic effort from a compiler to actually implement as an optimization but I don't see an obvious reason why it couldn't be done in principle. Does anyone know if this would not be permitted under the standard, or even if there are already implementations that do this optimization in practice?

Comment: How would this even be possible for dynamically-allocated arrays? What happens if you try to add more elements to a vector than there was room allocated in the containing object, for example?

Comment: the stl containers typically take customer allocators as template parameters, so yes, you could do this (yourself). If you want the compiler to do this automatically, use the stack :)

Comment: Like I said, it would require heroic efforts from a compiler to detect this in all but the most trivial of cases. I'm curious if it's allowed in principle and if any compilers do it in practice for even simple cases.

Comment: Yes, you can get behavior like this using a custom allocator. I have an example here: http://ideone.com/umU1UC. What I'm curious about is if the spec allows for an implementation to perform this optimization.

Comment: @mattnewport If by "heroic" you mean "only possible in contrived examples" then yes. The compiler has *no idea* how many elements you want to put in a vector. There is no way for it to detect this in basically every reasonable use-case. I'm not saying that coalescing allocations are not possible, but they are definitely not even remotely *feasible* in the vector case specifically, particularly because one must accommodate the possibility that the vector will grow.

Comment: @cdhowie If you had a simple struct similar to the Mesh example in the video and the compiler could determine that in all cases certain allocations were always performed together (i.e. the sizes of several containers had some fixed relation to each other) then it is doable, though even this would be an impressive optimization to achieve.

Comment: @cdhowie And yes, `std::vector` is not the best candidate for an optimization like this, it applies more to containers with semantics like `std::dynarray`.

Comment: @mattnewport Right, yes, that would be a very good candidate for such an optimization... assuming that the programmer doesn't assign one `dynarray` to another, or do anything silly, like given a class member `std::dynarray<int> m_dynarray;`, `m_dynarray.~dynarray(); new (&m_dynarray) std::dynarray<int>(100000);` which IIRC exhibits defined behavior. There are a lot of complex gotchas here.

Comment: @cdhowie Sure, no doubt it would be a heroic optimizer :) If the optimizer has global visibility of the relevant code it seems possible though.

Comment: @mattnewport Yup, agreed. And if the coder does some UB that tricks the optimizer, well... it's UB. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the standard allows coalescing allocations (C++14):

> #### 5.3.4 New `[expr.new]`
>
> 10 An implementation is allowed to omit a call to a replaceable global allocation function (18.6.1.1, 18.6.1.2).
>   When it does so, the storage is instead provided by the implementation or provided by extending the
>   allocation of another *new-expression*. The implementation may extend the allocation of a *new-expression* `e1`
>   to provide storage for a *new-expression* `e2` if the following would be true were the allocation not extended:
>
> - the evaluation of `e1` is sequenced before the evaluation of `e2`, and
> - `e2` is evaluated whenever e1 obtains storage, and
> - both `e1` and `e2` invoke the same replaceable global allocation function, and
> - if the allocation function invoked by `e1` and `e2` is throwing, any exceptions thrown in the evaluation
>     of either `e1` or `e2` would be first caught in the same handler, and
> - the pointer values produced by `e1` and `e2` are operands to evaluated *delete-expressions*, and
> - the evaluation of `e2` is sequenced before the evaluation of the *delete-expression* whose operand is the pointer value produced by `e1`.

C++11 did not allow coalescing or omitting such allocations.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the information I was looking for!

Comment: @Casey so this is new language for C++14?

Comment: @mattnewport Yes. See [N3664](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3664.html), adopted into the C++14 working paper in May 2013 (per the editor's report [N3692](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3692.html)).

Comment: It should be noted that this is only about *replaceable* global allocation functions. If the compiler can detect that `new` and friends are not replaced , then anything is permitted under the as-if rule.

Comment: @n.m.: Well, if there is no observable difference, of course the compiler can do whatever it wants. That's nothing new though, the as-if rule must always be accounted for.